# Insertar un registro sino EXISTE de lo contrario ACTUALIZARLO MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysqli

buenas amigos espero puedan ayudarme, tengo la siguiente **tabla**

```
 CREATE TABLE `almacen_articulo` (
`id` INT(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`existencia` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`id_articulo` VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`id_almacen` VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`existencia_comprome` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 )
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
AUTO_INCREMENT=4
;
```

**estos son los datos que contienen**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi intencion es hacer un **insert del articulo 85 en el almacen 2 sino exite, de lo contrario si ya existe en ese almacen actualizar su existencia**

He probado esta consulta pero sigue haciendo el insert en vez de actulizarlo

```
INSERT INTO almacen_articulo (id_articulo,id_almacen,existencia) VALUES(85, 2, 100) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id_articulo=85, id_almacen=2, existencia=100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que funcione, tendrías que definir los campos *id_articulo* e *id_almacen* como `UNIQUE` o `PRIMARY KEY`. Aquí tienes la info de `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: muchas Gracias muy agrdecido!